# SharePoint Custom master page issue

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

After having custom master page, site setting icon diminished and onclick dropdown option comes as mis-aligned.[image]. It should be like this[image] Could anyone help me to fix this issue? Thanks in advance

Comment: Without the CSS and markup for your custom master page (the relevant portions) it is hard to help you

Comment: To help debug this issue you should use developer tools (F12), use the element-picker and check what he computed values of those elements are

Comment: computed values?!?